# Anonymous edit of recent user questions

Tags: discussion

Interesting case with the question [Regex to remove certain patterns from urls](https://serverfault.com/questions/1100789/regex-to-remove-certain-patterns-from-urls) .

The user who asked this was recently registered. The profile is empty and this is their first question.

Then there is an edit https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/520382 which is coming from "anonymous". This edit does not just improve the question with better formatting, grammar/language, fixing links, or even moving info from comments, but it provides some additional information.

This must be the same user who forgot to authenticate? Or this could be the vandalism, somebody tries to divert an attention and prevent the original user to receive valid answers?

Should I accept edits in such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a complex situation as you have no tool to detect if it come from the real user.

The actual edit got rejected from other reviewers and I would suggest to **reject** too.

Most case I seen in the past was a bad site usage from another user. Someone that got the same symptoms and the edit bring back the question active. It bring bad case where the one editing can't never mark an answer as the question got hijacked.

For the actual case I can confirm it was probably the same user. I will left a comment to notify the user to register to edit.

Thanks for spotting it, so I will warn the user